Buscar las palabras que contengan una letra en una lista ,arreglo o matriz C#
Necesito hacer un tipo buscador, en donde si escribo la letra a, muestre las palabras de un arreglo, que contengan esa letra en cualquiera de sus índices.
Por ejemplo:
 List<string> Lista1 = [ "Casa", "Árbol", "Reloj", "Botón", "Bota"];

Quiero que muestre las palabras que tengan la letra o carácter a:

Casa
Árbol
Bota


Edita tu pregunta y pon el código que has intentado

Preguntas por una lista, arreglo o matriz, pero yo solo veo una lista. No parece que hayas intentado resolverlo por tí mismo ni tampoco parece que le hayas preguntado a ChatGPT ni a Copilot. Me parece poco ético pedir a la gente del foro que emplee su tiempo y esfuerzo en contestar tu pregunta cuando tú no te esfuerzas en absoluto y ni siquiera tienes la amabilidad de marcar la respuesta de Yussef como correcta

1) Buscar las palabras que contengan la letra "a"
List<string> Lista1 = [ "Casa", "Árbol", "Reloj", "Botón", "Bota","ALo" ];
var result = Lista1.Where(palabra => palabra.Contains('a'));

Resultado:
Casa
Bota


2) Buscar las palabras que contengan la letra "a", sin importar mayúsculas o minúsculas
List<string> Lista1 = [ "Casa", "Árbol", "Reloj", "Botón", "Bota","ALo" ];
var result = Lista1.Where(palabra => palabra.Contains('a',StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

Resultado:
Casa
Bota
ALo


2) Buscar las palabras que contengan la letra "a", sin importar mayúsculas o minúsculas, y sin que importen las tildes
Para esto usaremos Normalize, ejemplo
String p = "Código";
Console.WriteLine(p.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)); //imprime Co´digo

De esta manera separamos la vocal de la tilde y así podemos comprobar correctamente si la letra existe dentro de la palabra.
List<string> Lista1 = [ "Casa", "Árbol", "Reloj", "Botón", "Bota","ALo" ];
var result = Lista1.Where(palabra => palabra.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Contains('a',StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));        

Resultado:
Casa
Árbol
Bota
ALo

